# Setting HTML dir attribute on individual list elements in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, html-lists

I'm trying to render an HTML ordered list in which individual elements need to render with right-to-left text and others left-to-right (e.g. Hebrew and English. No, it won't look great.)

Sticking a `dir="rtl/ltr"` attribute on the `<li>` elements gives me heterogeneous rendering in Firefox but not in Chrome, where it's always left-to-right ([example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r30gqcLu/)).

Is there some way I can achieve cross-browser consistency here, other than abandoning list elements for `<div>`s (which work as desired.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because chrome will default set `text-align: -webkit-match-parent;`

Add following in css will solved your issue.

```
 li {
        text-align: unset;
    }
```

Check [Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/r30gqcLu/1/)

Comment: I would go with this (ketans) answer above the alternative http://stackoverflow.com/a/29119931/404335

Comment: apologies, clarified what I meant - yours is likely the better of the two approaches +1

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the following CSS:

```
li[dir=rtl]{
    direction: rtl;
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override; 
    text-align:right;
}
```

This will give you exactly [**the same rendering in FF and chrome**](https://jsfiddle.net/r30gqcLu/3/)